# onkeyup not working on dynamically create multiple textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

here i'm creating multiple textarea dynamically
for example :

```
<div id="div1">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" onkeyup='javascript:countChar(this);'></textarea>
 <div id='charCount'>250</div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" onkeyup='javascript:countChar(this);'></textarea>
 <div id='charCount'>250</div>
</div>

<div id="div3">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" onkeyup='javascript:countChar(this);'></textarea>
 <div id='charCount'>250</div>
</div>

<div id="div4">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" onkeyup='javascript:countChar(this);'></textarea>
 <div id='charCount'>250</div>
</div>
```

my JS Code :

```
function countChar(val) {
    var len = val.value.length;
    if (len >= 250) {
        val.value = val.value.substring(0, 250);
    } else {
        $("#charCount").text(250 - len);
        $("#charCount1").text(250 - len);
    }
};
```

this code is working fine with first textarea but not working with other textarea, if i edit div id manually `for example : <div id='charCount2'>250</div>` now 2nd div also working.

Comment: because ids are singular...

Answer (score 0):

You can not have multiple elements with the same id. So you need to select the element that is a sibling of the text area. There are mutltiple ways of doing it, but with your layout, you can use next()

```
$(val).next().text(250 - len);
```

other option select parent and find the div

```
$(val).parent().find("div").text(250-len);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use `.next(SELECTOR)` to get the next element of the current element.

Note: `ID` attribute must be unique in a document. Also consider using `jQuery` `.on` handler to bind events than inline event binding.

```js
function countChar(val) {
  var len = val.value.length;
  if (len >= 250) {
    val.value = val.value.substring(0, 250);
  } else {
    $(val).next(".charCount").text(250 - len);
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" onkeyup='javascript:countChar(this);'></textarea>
  <div class='charCount'>250</div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" onkeyup='javascript:countChar(this);'></textarea>
  <div class='charCount'>250</div>
</div>

<div id="div3">
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" onkeyup='javascript:countChar(this);'></textarea>
  <div class='charCount'>250</div>
</div>

<div id="div4">
  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" onkeyup='javascript:countChar(this);'></textarea>
  <div class='charCount'>250</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using the same id attribute for more than one element in your DOM, however, you could still get your code to run using jQuery traversing methods to be more specific on which #charCount to udpate:

```
function countChar(val) {
  var len = val.value.length;
  if (len >= 250) {
    val.value = val.value.substring(0, 250);
  } else {
    $(val).parent().find("#charCount").text(250 - len);        
  }
};
```

### Better solution using classes

Use class selector instead of id:

```
function countChar(val) {
    var len = val.value.length;
    if (len >= 250) {
        val.value = val.value.substring(0, 250);
    } else {
        $(val).parent().find(".charCount").text(250 - len);        
    }
};
```

And your html

```
<div id="div1">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" onkeyup='javascript:countChar(this);'></textarea>
 <div class='charCount'>250</div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" onkeyup='javascript:countChar(this);'></textarea>
 <div class='charCount'>250</div>
</div>

<div id="div3">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" onkeyup='javascript:countChar(this);'></textarea>
 <div class='charCount'>250</div>
</div>

<div id="div4">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" onkeyup='javascript:countChar(this);'></textarea>
 <div class='charCount'>250</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **[maxlength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea)** to limit your textareas to 250 characters:

```
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" maxlength="250"></textarea>
```

Define your events through jQuery instead of inline, and use the `input` event:

```
$('textarea').on('input', function() {
  $(this).next().text(250 - $(this).val().length);
});
```

`$(this).next()` targets the div that should be updated.

```js
$('textarea').on('input', function() {
  $(this).next().text(250 - $(this).val().length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" maxlength="250"></textarea>
 <div id='charCount'>250</div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" maxlength="250"></textarea>
 <div id='charCount'>250</div>
</div>

<div id="div3">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" maxlength="250"></textarea>
 <div id='charCount'>250</div>
</div>

<div id="div4">
 <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" maxlength="250"></textarea>
 <div id='charCount'>250</div>
</div>
```